# Let $f(z) = z^4 - 2z^3 + z^2$. Evaluate $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int \frac{f'}{f} dz$ and $\int \frac{zf'}{f} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z) = z^4 - 2z^3 + z^2$. Evaluate $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f'}{f} dz$ and $\int_C \frac{zf'}{f} dz$ where $C: |z| = R$ for $R >> 1$.

**Attempt**

For the first integral, I think we can simply use Rouche's Theorem with $h(z)=z^4$ and $g(z)=- 2z^3 + z^2$. Since $|h(z)| > |g(z)|$ everywhere on $C$, we have by the argument principle that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f'}{f} dz = 4.$$

The second integral evaluates to $2 \pi i$ times the sum of the values of the zeros. Since the zeros are located at $0$ and $1$, each with multiplicity $2$, we have
$$\int_C \frac{zf'}{f} dz = 4 \pi i.$$

I'm not sure how to validate my work. Is this the right way to approach these integrals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your results are correct, and your approach is *a* right way to approach it.

For the first integral, there is no need to invoke Rouché's theorem, the residue theorem (in the form of the argument principle) directly yields that the value is the number of zeros (counting multiplicities) enclosed by $C$ - which for large $R$ is the total number of zeros, and that is the degree of the polynomial.

For the second integral, one does not need to find the zeros of the polynomial - here that's easy enough, but in general it can be hard. One can use that for a monic polynomial, the sum of the zeros is the negative of the coefficient of $z^{\deg f - 1}$, so the sum of the zeros (counting multiplicities) can be read off the polynomial without computation.

Comment: Is there a theorem that states the result you are using for the sum of the zeros of a monic polynomial?

Comment: You get it from the product representation of the polynomial. If $p$ is monic and has zeros $\zeta_1,\dotsc,\zeta_k$, where each zero is listed according to its multiplicity, then $$p(z) = \prod_{\kappa = 1}^k (z - \zeta_{\kappa}),$$ and multiplying that product out gives you $$p(z) = z^k - \Biggl(\sum_{\kappa = 1}^k \zeta_{\kappa}\Biggr)z^{k-1} + \dotsc + (-1)^k \prod_{\kappa = 1}^k \zeta_{\kappa}.$$ If $p$ isn't monic, say $p(z) = a_kz^k + a_{k-1}z^{k-1} + \dotsc + a_0$, then the sum of the zeros is $-\dfrac{a_{k-1}}{a_k}$.